# Magento Remove back link from Create an Account Page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

In create an account page, After all the text boxes, we can see submit button and back links. I wnat to disable the back link functionality in this page. I have seen the customer.xml, but nothing is related to this page. I think it is coming from the customer/account/link/back.phtml. But how to disable this functionality???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- I found right path to remove Back line it can be either of below both path:

--app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml
--app\design\frontend\yourtheme\yourtheme\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml

Between line no 175 to 180

Give php comments or delete that code

Thanks...

Comment: Thank you sir.. Thank u so much.. It works.. But what is the persistenet folder for?? Why it contains register form and login form??

Answer (score 1):

In normal scenario username,pwd or any data is stored in browsers cookies but magento provides this facility that when user name and passowrd or any cart item added in cart it stores in database table in persistent storage. So if same user adds any item to cart and login from another browser he can view his items from other browser as well. I also have not much research on it, but while surfing i got this much information .I will provide you one link wich can help you undestanding concept better... http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/persistent-shopping-cart-customer-segmentation-just-getting-better/

Comment: Thank u for ur detail explination sir.. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the functionality by copying /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/nostate/customer/form/register.phtml to your template and editing or deleting lines 174 & 337 `<p class="back-link"><a href="<?php echo $this->escapeUrl($this->getBackUrl()) ?>" class="back-link"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a></p>`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, but no luck for me.It is same as previous. In my register.phtml I have only line no.173 , I dont have 337. In your answer what is 'nostate' means?? I dont have an folder named upon this...

Comment: in addition: just to be sure which file to change, you can enable template path hints (http://www.redlightblinking.com/blog/magento-debugging-how-to-debug-template-paths-logging-and-display-errors). Reload your page and you'll see which files generate your view.

Answer (score 0):

Following path is For removing Back Line that is :

\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\form\register.phtml
Delete Line (Line No 177)

Answer (score 0):

Copy register.phtml from \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\form\register.phtml to \app\design\frontend\Your_Theme\default\template\customer\form\register.phtml

And at around line no 176  you will find code for Remove button just comment it